How can I get the selected option from <select> in HTML code?
I'm trying to get the selected option from <select> element in HTML using BeautifulSoup, but I have a problem that the source HTML doesn't indicate selected elements in code. The source looks like that:
<select class="class_name" name="Type" style="max-width: 170px; min-width: 135px;">
    <option value="Value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="Value2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="Value3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="Value4">Value 4</option>
</select>

Meanwhile this is how the element looks in browser:

So when I try soup.find('select', class_="class_name"), i only get a list of options, but not selected one:
<select class="class_name" name="Type" style="max-width: 170px; min-width: 135px;"><option value="Value1">Value 1</option><option value="Value2">Value 2</option><option value="Value3">Value 3</option><option value="Value4">Value 4</option></select>

What can help me in this case?

you are selecting the container tag for the options that's why you get a list and not an individual one

In case that there is no indicator like selected there will be no chance to pick the right one.
In case that there is an indicator:
soup.select_one('select option[selected]').get('value')

Example
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<select class="class_name" name="Type" style="max-width: 170px; min-width: 135px;">
    <option value="Value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="Value2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="Value3" selected>Value 3</option>
    <option value="Value4">Value 4</option>
</select>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select_one('select option[selected]').get('value')

